# SASS compile error when using variable with media query

Tags: sass

This is kind of simple, when compiling the following code fails with the error:

**Line 6 of media.scss: Invalid CSS after "...ia (min-width: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "$desktop**

Here is the code (as simple as possible):

```
$desktop: 1920px;
$tablet: 1024px;
$phone: 480px;

// Style adjustments for desktop size
@media (min-width: $desktop) {

}

// Style adjustments for tablet size
@media (min-width: $tablet) and (max-width: $desktop) {

}

// Style adjustments for phone size
@media (max-width: $phone) {

}
```

Is this a bug? Maybe it's not possible to use variables in media queries with SASS.

Comment: You need to upgrade your version of Sass.

Comment: Yes you were right, had to update Sass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem with the code. Variables are possible in SASS 3.2. [Link](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/responsive-web-design-in-sass-using-media-queries-in-sass-32)

Comment: Seems that I really had an old Sass version installed. After running "sudo gem update" it works. Thnx a lot.